# Stateful hash signature without Merkle trees

Tags: signature, hash-signature, one-time-signature

When it comes to stateful schemes, would you really need to use a Merkle tree?

Couldn't you sign the hash of the message concatenated to the hash of the new public key?

New public key: hash(hash(message) || hash(WOTS+/lamport public key))

Then for every new signature you include the previous signature(s) (without the messages).

Is the only downside of this the growing signature size or is there a security fault?

Comment: There is a sort of security leak in that you must attach the hashes for all previously-signed files to any new signature. (But also, yeah, a signature that grows like that is horrendous outside of an academic context.)

Comment: (Possible mitigation to this leak: salting messages before you sign them)

Answer (score -3):

This is how stealth addresses are generated in Haircomb, you hash garbage values together with existing public key, to get a new public key. The garbage values have a specific format, that is of liquidity stack which pays 0 coins to the garbage address.

It isn't really a signature scheme, but rather a commit-reveal commitment scheme.